# Underscore Javascript building frequency graph

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am currently pretty new to JS and underscore. I want to see which particular number occurs the most in a given array, (say var a for now). As an avid python user, I am used to summing it up in a frequency telegraph and then output it in tuples [(1, 3), (2, 2), ... ] and then sort it like that.

What is the best way to do so in javascript?

```
function votesTied() { 
  var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7];
  var tele = {};
  _.each(a, function(key) { 
    if (tele[key]) { 
      tele[key]++;
    } else { 
      tele[key] = 1;
    }
  });

  var items = _.map(tele, function(frequency,key) { return [key,frequency]; });
  var results = _.sortBy(items, function(tuple) { return -1 * tuple[1]; }).value(); 

  return results.length > 1 && results[0][1] == results[1][1];
}
```

I ask so because I can literally do all this in 1 line of python. I am sure there's a more elegant way to write this in underscore or javascript.

Answer (score 5):

It's unfortunate that **underscore**'s `map()` function is unable to return an object with maintained properties, because that would have allowed for something like:

```
var t = _.chain (a)
          .groupBy (function (p) { return p; })
          .map (function (e) { return _.size (e); })
          .value ();
```

but short of rewriting the function to allow for this, the best I could come up with is this:

```
var t = {};
_.chain (a)
  .groupBy (function (p) { return p; })
  .each (function (e, i) {
    t[i] = _.size (e);
  });
```

This will collect everything in `t`.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't let it be, so I checked the source for **underscore**'s `map()` and made the following changes to allow for the first snippet above:

```
  _.map = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    // determine the return type
    if (_.isArray (obj)) {
        var results = [];
    }
    else {
        var results = {};
    }
    if (obj == null) return results;
    // @xxx: we need to override the native map(), thus the next line is commented out
    // if (nativeMap && obj.map === nativeMap) return obj.map(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      results[index] = iterator.call(context, value, index, list);
    });
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) results.length = obj.length;
    return results;
  };
```

I haven't checked it that thoroughly though, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this?

```
result = _.chain(a)
    .groupBy(function(x) { return x })
    .map(function(v, k) { return [k, v.length] })
    .sortBy(function(x) { return -x[1] })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a second way to achieve the result you want, that requires no modification of the code. The clarity of the code might be slightly reduced, but the steps required are fewer and it's still quite clear.

By using underscore's [reduce()](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) like this:

```
_.reduce([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 7], function(frequencies, value) {
  frequencies[value] = frequencies[value] && frequencies[value] + 1 || 1;
  return frequencies;
}, {});
```

As the documentation says, the first parameter to `reduce()` is the array to be reduced, the second is the reduction callback and the third is the initial state of the *memo* / *aggregation* - that is an empty object that we populate with the frequency data during the reduction.

The result should look like this:

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

That is an object with keys for each unique element and values with their respective frequency.

There is perhaps a slight reduction in clarity, but it's quite close to the requested *one-liner* and requires nothing more than stock underscore.